# how to clean option values under select - html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using two drop down(first drop-down category and second drop-down sub category) in a page,both drop-down will be loaded dynamically, in which I will be selecting a value from first drop-down accordingly I have to load value to second drop-down.I has done that,but thing is that it will get done for first time.

But when I click on some other option in states drop-down, its not getting updated on second drop-down.

And My code is:
This piece of code is to get list of category while loading page ie under document.ready

```
$.ajax({
    url : "../category/getCategory",
    type : "post",
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data) {
        var categoryBOs = data.categoryBOs;
        $.each(categoryBOs, function(key, value) {
            $("#productCategory").append(
                    '<option value='+value.categoryId+'>'
                            + value.categoryName
                            + '</option>');
        });
    }

});
```

This part of ajax is to load sub category

```
$("#productCategory").on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
    $.ajax({
        url : "../category/getSubCategory",
        type : "post",
        cache : false,
        dataType : "json",
        data : "categoryId=" + $(this).val(),
        success : function(data) {
            var subCategoryBOs = data.subCategoryBOs;

            $.each(subCategoryBOs, function(key, subCategoryBO) {
                subCategories.push({lable:subCategoryBO.categoryId , value:subCategoryBO.categoryName});
                 $("#productSubCategory").append(
                        '<option value='+subCategoryBO.categoryId+'>'
                                + subCategoryBO.categoryName
                                + '</option>'); 
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `$("#productCategory").empty()` before the first `$.each` and `$("#productSubCategory").empty()` before the second `$.each`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in your code you always append new entries, yet never remove old ones before. So possibly your list just keeps getting longer with new entries at its end? Try to remove the entries before append new ones:

```
$("#productSubCategory option").remove();
$("#productSubCategory").append(
    '<option value=' + subCategoryBO.categoryId + '>' + subCategoryBO.categoryName + '</option>');
```

In my experience $.each with $.append can get very slow at some amount of list entries. I would rewrite it in native javascript with for() and createElement().

Answer (score 0):

you need to make `html` in `.each` and append after `.each` end. No option change from first drop down you need to remove the previous on by using `$("#productSubCategory option").remove();`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../category/getCategory",
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var categoryBOs = data.categoryBOs;
        var html = '';
        $.each(categoryBOs, function (key, value) {
            html += '<option value=' + value.categoryId + '>' + value.categoryName + '</option>';
        });

        $("#productCategory").append(html);
    }

});  


$("#productCategory").on('change', function () {
    alert($(this).val());
    $.ajax({
        url: "../category/getSubCategory",
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: "categoryId=" + $(this).val(),
        success: function (data) {
            var subCategoryBOs = data.subCategoryBOs;
            var html = '';
            $.each(subCategoryBOs, function (key, subCategoryBO) {
                subCategories.push({ lable: subCategoryBO.categoryId, value: subCategoryBO.categoryName });
                html += '<option value=' + subCategoryBO.categoryId + '>' + subCategoryBO.categoryName + '</option>';
            });
            $("#productSubCategory").append(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple thing you have to do here is that every time when you  load sub-categories just place following before that .

```
 $(dropdown).empty();
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select#catname").change(function () {
   
 // part of code 

          $("#subcatname").append($newOpt1); 

// appending the category of dropdown
        }
        $("#subcatname").trigger('contentChanged');
  // changing the contenet
      }
    });
    $("select#subcatname").change(function () {
    // something changes after trigger in dropdown
  });

// removing the content or clearing the content after selecting
       $("#subcatname").empty();

  });     
});
```